# Difference between quartz2d on iphone and mac

Tags: iphone, macos, 2d, quartz-graphics

There is difference between quartz2d on iphone and mac? where can i find a list of that? Every  book i founded in amazon is dedicate to programming quartz on mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the low-level drawing goes, the two platforms are almost identical.  One issue that you'll encounter is that many of those guides were written before Leopard was released, so they don't take into account Core Animation layer backing for views, which is present everywhere on the iPhone.

You don't have access to some of the text drawing systems on the iPhone that you do on the Mac.

Another key difference between the two platforms is the coordinate space for Quartz drawing.  Standard Quartz on the Mac has the lower left corner be (0,0), where the backing layers for UIViews have a flipped geometry with the upper left corner being (0,0).  I provide a little more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868052/how-does-the-coordinate-system-in-an-cgcontextref-look-like/868621#868621).